# The meaning of γt−t0 in Reinforcement learning with pytorch

Tags: reinforcement-learning, pytorch

When reading [pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html):

> Our aim will be to train a policy that tries to maximize the discounted, cumulative reward `Rt0=∑∞t=t0γt−t0rt`, where `Rt0` is also known as the return

I know γ is the discount factor, but I am not sure that what `t-t0` of`γt−t0` mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with reinformcement learning, however looking at the figure I think I understand what is meant. Gamma is the discount factor, which is taken to the power `t-t0`, i.e. the number of episodes starting from `t`. This gives the discount factor for a specific episode, which is then multiplied by the return of that episode, `r_t`, to get the discounted reward for one specific episode. The total return is then computed by summing all the future rewards for future episodes.

Comment: You are right, thank you :)